# How to extract a diagonal part of a matrix?

Tags: image, image-processing, matrix, matlab-figure

I have the indices of a slanted rectangle in an image and i would like to take all the pixel values of that slanted rectangle and put it in a matrix so i will be able to calculate the mean of the columns and other things. How can i extract the values of the rectangle and put them in aמ orderly way into the matrix?
[image]

I added an image that shows a slanted rectangle, and i want to take all the pixel values inside that rectangle and put it into a matrix so i will be able to work with the matrix functions i know.

Comment: What do you expect the resulting matrix to look like? For example, do you just want to mask the rectangular area and leave the remainder of the image with zero (or NaN) values? Or do you want to rotate the rectangle so that all of the matrix values are valid (though interpolated)?

Comment: I would like to rotate the rectangle. Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: Have you tried [imrotate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html)?